# Animating the file upload button using CSS

Tags: html, css

I've a form in which I've a file upload filed I did customized it to fit the color theme which the `PHP` form is using it works but it's just static. I wanted to add a small transition to the button which I archived following the W3Schools tutorial.

But after that I'm facing a problem which I really don't have an idea how to solve. I did a search on this matter but most answers suggest to use `bootstrap` which I also tried and it messed up my current projects `CSS`.

Can some one show me what I'm doing wrong with the animation part.

```css
.fileUpload {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #4068E0;
  color: white;
  height: 30px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #4068E0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-transition: prop 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: prop 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: prop 0.4s;
  -o-transition: prop 0.4s;
  transition: prop 0.4s;
}

.fileUpload:after {
  content: "";
  background: #85b7e8;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  padding-top: 300%;
  padding-left: 350%;
  margin-left: -20px!important;
  margin-top: -120%;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.fileUpload:active:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0s
}

.fileUpload input.upload {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.fileName {
  margin: 2px 0 0 130px;
  width: auto;
}

.updLabel {
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#uploadFile {
  border: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="usrCreate-form-right">
  <div class="fileUpload">
    <span class="updLabel">Add Image</span>
    <input type="file" id="uploadFile" class="upload">
  </div>
  <div class="fileName">
    <input id="uploadFile" placeholder="0 files selected" disabled>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the above snippet the animation does happens but it doesn't pop the file selection window. If I disable the animation part it does pop up I tried few other things which also didn't work that's why I decided to ask here.

Comment: The below answers might solve the issue, don't use the same ids for different elements

Comment: Oh thx I didn't see that there's 2 inputs with the same ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got success with your code when I add a z-index on the input. I tried with `z-index: 1` and it worked. the visuals on the button won't change.

```
.fileUpload > input {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I should have figured that out (face palm) thank you.I think my brain is frozen,